# All O(1) functions take exactly the same amount of time to run. True or False?

Tags: python

"All O(1) functions take exactly the same amount of time to run." True or false? Can anybody explain the answer to me?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_time#Constant_time

Comment: no its not, it just always confused me

Comment: Depending on the constants hidden behind the big-O notation (and input size), an `O(1)` function could take longer to run than an `O(N!)` function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

False. O(1) means **constant time**. This means that no matter what the size of the input is, the function will run in more or less the same amount of time - the runtime does not scale with the input.

This means that two O(1) functions will each run in constant time, though their constants may be different. So if you have two O(1) functions `f` and `g`, each of which compute the same result, expecting similar inputs (lets say they expect lists, for the sake of discussion), the runtime of `f` does not depend on the size of the list; nor does the runtime of `g`.

However, if `f` makes more complicated (or otherwise time-consuming) steps to compute the answer than does `g`, then `f`'s runtime will be more than `g`'s - the number of seconds required for `f` to terminate (let's call this value `fsec`) will be more than the number of seconds required for `g` to terminate (let's call this value `gsec`). Still, neither `fsec` nor `gsec` depend on the size of the input list - they'll be the same no matter how big or small the input list - but `gsec` will always be smaller than `fsec`.

It is because the runtime does not depend on the size of the input list that they are classified as O(1) algorithms - NOT because they perform a particular number of operations.

Comment: "runtime does not depend on the size of the input" -- incorrect.  The runtime of O(1) algorithms may depend on the size of the input, as long as the runtime is bounded by a constant which does not depend on the input size.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: "runtime is bounded by a constant which does not depend on the size of input" is equivalent to saying runtime <= C, where C = f(x) and x is not input.size; i.e. runtime = f(x), where x is not input.size; i.e. runtime is a function of something that is not the input size i.e. runtime is not a function of the input size. This means runtime does not depend on the size of the input

Comment: You say "runtime <= C" and "C = f(x)" and then you conclude "runtime = f(x)"... do you see the error here?  The correct conclusion is "runtime < f(x)".  Runtime can depend on input size as long as it's bounded.

Comment: For example, let `f(N) = 1 - exp(-N)`.  It's easy to show that f is O(1) even though it depends on N.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Alright, you're right there. Technically, that is true. However, O(1) is also bounded by f(N) = N^2. We need to find an `f` that *asymptotically* bounds the runtime - not just bounding the runtime

Comment: The reason I was not making the distinction between "bound" and "asymptotic bound" is because in the constant case, there is no difference -- all constant bounds are asymptotic constant bounds and vice versa.  Also note that any O(1) function is also an O(N) function, and any O(N) function is also an O(N^2) function.  You are thinking of "big theta" notation.  Θ(1) functions are not Θ(N) functions.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Ah yes! Thank you for clearing that up. I felt like I was missing something but couldn't quite put my finger on it - price of doing this at 3AM, I'm afraid :)